# WPF Change Binding values on update

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have a ListView that is as follows:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding OrganizationInfo}">
    <DockPanel>
        <StackPanel Width="130">
            <!-- Name -->
            <Label Content="Organization Name" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Margin="4" Height="25" />
            <!-- Street 1-->
            <Label Content="Address 1" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Margin="4" Height="25" />
            <!-- Street 2-->
            <Label Content="Address 2" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Margin="4" Height="25" />
            <!-- City -->
            <Label Content="City" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Margin="4" Height="25" />
            <!-- State -->
            <Label Content="State" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Margin="4" Height="25" />
            <!-- Zip -->
            <Label Content="Zip" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Margin="4" Height="25" />
            <!-- County -->
            <Label Content="County" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Margin="4" Height="25" />
            <!-- Service Area -->
            <Label Content="Service Area" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Margin="4" Height="25" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Width="330">
            <ComboBox Name="OrgNameComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Organizations}" SelectedValue="{Binding OrganizationName}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0 4" Height="25" />
            <TextBox Name="OrgStreet1TextBox" Text="{Binding OrgStreet1}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0 4" Height="25" />
            <TextBox Name="OrgStreet2TextBox" Text="{Binding OrgStreet2}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0 4" Height="25" />
            <TextBox Name="OrgCityTextBox" Text="{Binding OrgCity}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0 4" Height="25" />
            <TextBox Name="OrgStateTextBox" Text="{Binding OrgState}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0 4" Width="30" Height="25" />
            <TextBox Name="OrgZipTextBox" Text="{Binding OrgZip}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0 4" Width="60" Height="25" />
            <TextBox Name="OrgCountyTextBox" Text="{Binding OrgCounty}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0 4" IsEnabled="False" Height="25" />
            <TextBox Name="OrgServiceAreaTextBox" Text="{Binding OrgServiceArea}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0 4" IsEnabled="False" Height="25" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</ListView>
```

It is bound through a ViewModel:

```
class OutreachEventViewModel
{        
    //SQL TableAdapters & DataTables
    internal readonly OrganizationListTableAdapter OrganizationListTableAdapter = new OrganizationListTableAdapter();
    internal readonly OrgByNameTableAdapter OrgByNameTableAdapter = new OrgByNameTableAdapter();

    public ObservableCollection<string> Organizations { get; set; }
    public string OrganizationName { get; set; }

    //ViewModel that populates the contact listbox
    public OutreachEventViewModel()
    {
        //Perform SQL querys
        var organizations = OrganizationListTableAdapter.GetOrganizationList();

        //Declare needed variables
        var organizationList = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        //Store SQL results into lists
        organizationList.AddRange((IEnumerable)(from DataRow row in organizations.Rows select row.ItemArray[0].ToString()));


        Organizations = organizationList;   //Set list as ItemsSource
    }

    //Some method to update Organization address information

    public class OrgAddress : ViewModelBase
    {
        private string _street1;
        private string _street2;
        private string _city;
        private string _state;
        private string _zip;
        private string _county;
        private string _serviceArea;

        public string OrgStreet1
        {
            get { return _street1; }
            set
            {
                if (_street1 != value)
                {
                    Validator.ValidateProperty(value, new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "OrgStreet1" });
                    _street1 = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("OrgStreet1");
                }
            }
        }

        public string OrgStreet2
        {
            get { return _street2; }
            set
            {
                if (_street2 != value)
                {
                    Validator.ValidateProperty(value, new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "OrgStreet2" });
                    _street2 = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("OrgStreet2");
                }
            }
        }

        public string OrgCity
        {
            get { return _city; }
            set
            {
                if (_street1 != value)
                {
                    Validator.ValidateProperty(value, new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "OrgCity" });
                    _city = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("OrgCity");
                }
            }
        }

        public string OrgState
        {
            get { return _state; }
            set
            {
                if (_state != value)
                {
                    Validator.ValidateProperty(value, new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "OrgState" });
                    _state = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("OrgState");
                }
            }
        }

        public string OrgZip
        {
            get { return _zip; }
            set
            {
                if (_zip != value)
                {
                    Validator.ValidateProperty(value, new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "OrgZip" });
                    _zip = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("OrgZip");
                }
            }
        }

        public string OrgCounty
        {
            get { return _county; }
            set
            {
                if (_county != value)
                {
                    Validator.ValidateProperty(value, new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "OrgCounty" });
                    _county = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("OrgCounty");
                }
            }
        }

        public string OrgServiceArea
        {
            get { return _serviceArea; }
            set
            {
                if (_serviceArea != value)
                {
                    Validator.ValidateProperty(value, new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "OrgServiceArea" });
                    _serviceArea = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("OrgServiceArea");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever the OrganizationName changes I want it to update the rest of the fields by querying SQL and then setting the bindings (OrgStreet1, OrgStreet2, OrgCity, OrgState, OrgZip, OrgCounty, OrgServiceArea).

I do not know how to do this however.

I want the address fields to stay empty as long as no organization has been selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put code on the CLR setter of your OrganizationName property, to update the rest of the properties however you want:

```
private string organizationName;

public string OrganizationName 
{ 
    get { return organizationName; }
    set
    {
        if (organizationName != value)
        {
            organizationName = value;
            UpdateOrganizationData();
            OnPropertyChanged("OrganizationName");
        }
    }
}
```

Then just query for the new information in the `UpdateOrganizationData` method, and you're set.